# how to keep same connection for a new snowflake worksheet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowfake how can you open a new worksheet with the same connectons for role, datawarehouse and schema? Everytime I open a new worksheet it removes all my settings and have to select them again

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the default_warehouse and default_namespace user parameters to the values you want to be used when you create a new sheet.

These defaults will be used for every new sheet. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to automatically create a sheet with the same context as a previous sheet - in case that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I like to add a block like the following to the top of each new worksheet (adjust as needed) and run as a block to set the context. It helps me quickly remember where I am: ---------------------
use role SYSADMIN;
use warehouse ABC_WH;
use database MY_DB;
use schema TEST;
---------------------